# android studio 2.2.3 design page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Is there any method to combine the design part(layouts) of android studio 2.2.3.It seems  hard to understand and most of the time the rendering problem occurs ,I want it to be like the older versions.could you resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can get rid off from this problem.

please follow the steps.

- Go to your layout.xml file
- Click on Design tab (at bottom of the page)
- Now at the top of the layout there are some options (e.g. your current device, theme option, your current api..etc) click on the drop-down of current Api.
- Now select your compatible API.

It will remove that problem of rendering.